# Error when Executing multiple lines in the Node.js REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to executing multiple lines in Nodes.js REPL mode as below. But I faced below error. How to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
{

... var foo = [];

... }
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:137:25)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:393:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I27jR.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute multiple lines, you can simply define an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), like this:

```
(function () {

    var foo = [];

})();
```